# Why is the potential difference and EMF not the same?

Tags: circuit-analysis

If EMF and the potential difference have a unit of volts, why are they different from each other?

Comment: This question is essentially asking for tuition on basic electronics, page 1 stuff. It's a Q&A site, rather than discussion forum, and can't be a personal tutorial service, which is effectively what you're asking for. VTC for those reasons. You'll find plenty of detailed and free documentation on this available on the internet for you to research and learn from. Hope you can see how the site works but refer to other high-voted questions for examples of what's well-regarded here. Thanks.

Comment: Do you have an example? Normally I would consider them to be almost synonyms. The only thing is that I tend to use EMF when I want to emphasize that the potential difference was created by induction.

Comment: You can have an EMF without any potential difference between any two points. For example a shorted battery or a single shorted turn on a transformer.

Comment: @KevinWhite EMF with zero potential difference is not possible or not conceptually meaningful as far as I can see. In both of the examples you give, the potential difference is not and cannot be zero. If the potential difference between two points is zero, then either the current is zero, or the two points are connected by a super-conductor. Maybe there is something that could be done with hall effect or something to create zero potential in the  presence of current flow. I don't know. But not in your examples.

Comment: @mkeith Superconducting solenoids work just fine as transformer windings, though. So zero impedance is not a problem for getting charge moving, and for adding energy to a solenoid, or removing energy from it.

Comment: @Kubahasn'tforgottenMonica Kevin White said that "you can have EMF without any potential difference", and he gave two examples. Both examples are examples in which the potential is not zero. As far as I can see windings with zero ESR also do not help to create a situation in which we have EMF without any potential difference. I never said you can't have current without potential difference. In my mind, if you short a voltage out with a super-conductor, then there is no voltage and no emf across the super-conductor (unless the current is so high that it ceases to be a super-conductor).

Comment: @mkeith - EMF is the force causing the current. It need not result in any potential difference. In my battery example the EMF will still be there even if you short the battery but there will be no PD measurable anywhere even though there is current. (ignoring the finite resistance in the short). A more exact example would be loop of resistive material (even copper) with a changing magnetic field within it (such as the shading loop in a shaded pole motor). There will be EMF generated but no PD measurable anywhere.

Comment: If you short a battery with a super-conductor, the current will be limited by the battery internal resistance, but there will be zero potential, I guess. OK, I guess I am wrong and @KevinWhite is right. But the induction cases are kind of complicated because measuring the voltage on a wire that is subject to induction is not really meaningful and there have been epic flamewars about that topic. The potential difference is not well defined.

Answer (score 7):

**electromotive force**,
abbreviation **E** or **emf**, energy per unit electric charge that is imparted by an energy source, such as an electric generator or a battery. [Britannica](https://www.britannica.com/science/electromotive-force)

**potential difference**
the difference in potential between two points that represents the work involved or the energy released in the transfer of a unit quantity of electricity from one point to the other. [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/potential%20difference)

I suggest that electromotive source suggests a source of power whereas potential difference, while it *could* measure an electromotive force, can be measured on a non-source element of a circuit such as a resistor.

Quick and easy:

- EMF is what batteries, generators and power supplies give.
- PD is what your voltmeter measures.

Comment: Electricity is not a potential field when changing magnetic fields are involved, which is probably why people don't talk about PD. Though everyone I know just talks about "voltage" in context.

Answer (score 3):

They are descriptions of somewhat different phenomena. EMF is more specific than voltage.

'EMF' is generally used to describe a *source* of voltage (energy or power) -- for example a coil moving in a magnetic field *generates* an EMF.

To *measure* the phenomenon generated, the result is described in volts -- e.g. a "voltmeter" could measure the EMF generated by the above coil.

If you have a circuit with a battery and some resistors, the battery can be described as generating an EMF of 1.5 V, while the same phenomenon across the resistors is described as a *voltage*.

EMF is also used to describe the (voltage) generated by a thermocouple -- or even the unwanted phenomenon generated by dissimilar metal junctions. Commonly batteries (and power supplies, solar cells etc.) are just described as *voltage sources*. This is not incorrect, just slightly less specific.